# jquery image slider for jquery mobile website

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have found a fancy looking cubic jquery image slider for jquery mobile website here:
http://m.jeep.com/en/mobile/vehicles/selector.html?app=bmo#&ui-state=dialog

Now I want to use this slider in one of my project.But I didn't found any resource of this kind of slider for mobile website in online.Now I need to know if there are this kind of slider on the internet ? Or do you know any useful resource of image slider for mobile site (I didn't find any effective resource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not find an image slider on the link posted, but there is a slider on the [homepage](http://m.jeep.com/en/mobile/index.html). If you had that in mind I found a resopnsive slider called [refineslide](http://alexdunphy.github.com/refineslide/). I did not test it but from reading the github files I believe the transition you are looking for is not the default you should use the 'cubeh' transition.

For the record, the jeep site doesn't use any ready plugin for that slider it is all inline code on that page. If you want try to copy and edit that if no copyright issues.

Comment: Thank you very much c s h. I am becoming frustrated to find out a horizontal or vertical cubic slideshow for mobile. Refinslider helps me.Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I just googled it.